# AMD Vision Engine Control Center (CCC) spontaneously breaks and will not run after that without full reinstall

Tags: amd-catalyst, amd-vision

I am running AMD FX system with Radeon 5800 HD video card, on Win7 x64 system.

I have had problems with Catalyst Control Center for awhile, when it runs and shows a blank white window with nothing in it (like [this](http://vvcap.net/db/xNn7lyHkIprNrlRh0q-a.htp)). ccc.exe process actually runs fine [in a dock](http://vvcap.net/db/fnKzT7ap0nYfFf6SCzsJ.htp): , but as soon as I click anyting, even "About", it [hangs](http://vvcap.net/db/pkPuoAhanPcw6xlAN8sx.htp).

I am running eyefinity group, so I didn't want to break that, because there was no way to create it without running CCC. Anyway, I eventually did have a need to run it and get it fixed.

It took me to remove original AMD software, reboot in safe mode, cleanup the files and registry, and then re-install it, and it worked.

First off, sorry for unprofessionally expressing myself, but: ATI folks, you suck. This is a known problem, and you won't lift a finger to fix it.

But what happened day later is: CCC (now "AMD Vision Engine Control Center") will not start AGAIN, and reboot doesn't help.

Is anybody here aware how to debug the issue? I can not constantly reinstall AMD software, it is completely messed up. I want some better way to fix it, that doesn't involve spending an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to fix it: http://blog.galets.net/2012/07/how-i-fixed-amd-vision-engine-control.html